# Azure Common Credentials: Error in connection to blob storage when retrieving access token in get_token_with_client_credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-service-principal

I am trying to connect to a blob storage with the ServicePrincipalCredentials class and I get this error randomly:

```
Error adal-python  OAuth2Client:Get Token request failed
```

The code that I use to connect to the blob storage is the following:

> ```
> from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials 
> from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService 
> from azure.storage.common import TokenCredential       
>
> credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant, resource=resource)
>
> token_credential = TokenCredential(credentials.token["access_token"])
>
> blob_ service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, token_credential=token_credential)
> ```

So the connection once works fine but when calling it at different times gives the error from above, when initializing the class **ServicePrincipalCredentials**. I am accessing the secondary endpoint of the storage account with the "-secondary" suffix in the account_name.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

The full trace of the error is the following:

```
2020-07-23 22:26:37,040 - adal-python - ERROR - 1719fb4a-1173-49dc-bfd4-62e493331d9a - OAuth2Client:Get Token request failed
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/oauth2_client.py", line 268, in get_token
    timeout=self._call_context.get('timeout', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kedro/io/core.py", line 158, in from_config
  data_set = class_obj(**config)  # type: ignore
File "/src/hvl/utils/datasets/csv_blob_dataset.py", line 113, in __init__
  _blob_service = self._connect(_credentials)
File "/src/hvl/utils/datasets/csv_blob_dataset.py", line 144, in _connect
  return self._connect_spi_access(_credentials)
File "/src/hvl/utils/datasets/csv_blob_dataset.py", line 155, in _connect_spi_access
  client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant, resource=resource
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 355, in __init__
  self.set_token()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 367, in set_token
  self.secret
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py", line 179, in acquire_token_with_client_credentials
  return self._acquire_token(token_func)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py", line 128, in _acquire_token
  return token_func(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py", line 177, in token_func
  return token_request.get_token_with_client_credentials(client_secret)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/token_request.py", line 310, in get_token_with_client_credentials
  token = self._oauth_get_token(oauth_parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/token_request.py", line 112, in _oauth_get_token
  return client.get_token(oauth_parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adal/oauth2_client.py", line 268, in get_token
  timeout=self._call_context.get('timeout', None))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
  raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: What is the value of `resource` in your code `credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant, resource=resource)`?

Comment: the value of resource is "https://storage.azure.com/"

Comment: Try to set the `resource` as `https://{storage name}.blob.core.windows.net/` or `https://{storage name}.blob.core.windows.net/.default` or `https://{storage name}-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/` or `https://{storage name}-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/.default`.